# Using "self" in UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, self

Sorry for stupid question, I'm newbie. Whole day I read a lot of answers and articles about using of `self`. But I still can't understand, why app crashes, if I change target from `self` to `faceView` in `UITapRecognizer`. What `self` refers to here? Is there any place in XCode to find it out? If you can advise any articles to read about this type of usage of `self`, it would be great too. Just in case, here is [GitHub link](https://github.com/kremlevmax/SmileMyFaceGestureRecognizer) to this project, if it's needed. Great thanks for help.

```
class FaceViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var faceView: FaceView!{
    didSet {
        let handlerPinch = #selector(FaceView.changeScale(byReactingOn:))
        let pichRecognizer = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: faceView, action: handlerPinch)
        faceView.addGestureRecognizer(pichRecognizer)

        let handlerTap = #selector(openEyes(byReactingOn:))
        let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: handlerTap)
        faceView.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
```

Comment: Just do not use `didSet` with `IBOutlet`s. Put the code in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: And you can pass either only the `GestureRecognizer` as action parameter or no parameter, nothing else.

Comment: `self` refers the current view controller instance; this is what you want. You do not want `faceView` to be the target of the gesture recogniser.

Comment: I copied this code from Stanford iOS course. But will try your advice. Thanks.

Comment: Paulw11, thanks! But why two GestureRecognizers use different targets?

Comment: I guess they want to handle the tap in the view controller and the pinch in the view. The Stanford course is good, but you should also read the Swift book in iBooks. `self` is a common concept in object oriented programming. Some languages (such as C#) use `this` instead of `self`

Comment: Thanks you! I think I have answers for my questions now. Have a great day!